# Json to php condition text part

Tags: php, json

I only want to display the text from the condition part, see the JSON below

```
"forecast": {
"forecastday": [
  {
    "date": "2017-12-01",
    "date_epoch": 1512086400,
    "day": {
      "maxtemp_c": 4.9,
      "maxtemp_f": 40.8,
      "mintemp_c": 0.9,
      "mintemp_f": 33.6,
      "avgtemp_c": 1.8,
      "avgtemp_f": 35.2,
      "maxwind_mph": 9.8,
      "maxwind_kph": 15.8,
      "totalprecip_mm": 0,
      "totalprecip_in": 0,
      "avgvis_km": 18,
      "avgvis_miles": 11,
      "avghumidity": 88,
      "condition": {
        "text": "Partly cloudy",
        "icon": "//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/day/116.png",
        "code": 1003
      },
      "uv": 0.5
    },
```

My code shows all the parts from condition, i only want the text part.
See my code below:

```
$json = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($json['forecast']['forecastday'] as $forecast) {
  echo 'date: '.$forecast['date'].'<br />';

  foreach ($forecast['day']['condition'] as $condition) {
    echo ''.$condition.'<br />';
  }
}
```

Comment: Made an edit to my code i had to use the api to see the exact format of the array. I tested the code and it is working. Accept my answer if it fits your question. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      $json = json_decode($json, true);



$counter=0;
foreach ($json['forecast']['forecastday'] as $forecast) {
    { if ($counter++ == 0) continue; }
   echo 'date: '.$forecast['date'].'<br />';
   echo 'date: '.$forecast['day']['condition']['text'].'<br />';


}
```

So a bit more explanation about how a multidimensional array works.
Each nested array should be treated-accessed/parsed as a new array. So in your example you have the main array `$json` , this is where magic starts.

After that in order to reach the `text` you need to map your array to find the route that will get you there. If you go for

```
print_r($json)
```

you will see that you get your whole array. Now you can see that you have to access `forecast` array first and so you do it like `$json['forecast']` and you are inside the nested array. Same logic leads you to `day` field.

**New Edit:** This will output your second record only.

Comment: Great! It works :) 
Is it possible to only output the second array?